# No funciona llamada a ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy armando una pagina como proyecto para registrar distintos eventos abriendo un modal para cada tipo. En este caso el problema me surge en el alta. Creo un formulario y al boton le doy el evento onclick para que se guarde directamente en la base de datos. 
El problema surge cuando doy "click" al botón no se ejecuta la llamada al ajax. Nose si estoy cometiendo algún error.
 Estuve leyendo un poco y la verdad nose bien que error tiene.
El resultado esperado es un alertify que diga que se dio de alta el registro.
Este seria el código del form dentro del modal en el index.php

```
<form>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col">
            <span>Fecha:</span>
            <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span>Farmacia:</span> 
            <select name="farmacia" class="custom-select" id="fcia">
                <?php 
                require('conexion.php');
                $registros=mysqli_query($conexion,"select idFarmacia, nombre from farmacias")
                            or die("Problemas con el select: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
                while ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) 
                {
                    echo "<option value=\"$reg[idFarmacia]\">$reg[nombre]</option>";
                }
                mysqli_close($conexion);
                ?>
            </select>   
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span>Tipo Insumo:</span>
            <select name="idtipoinsumo" class="custom-select" id="tipins">
                <?php 
                require('conexion.php');
                $registros=mysqli_query($conexion,"select idtipoInsumo, descripcion from tiposinsumos")
                            or die("Problemas con el select: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
                while ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) 
                {
                    echo "<option value=\"$reg[idtipoInsumo]\">$reg[descripcion]</option>";
                }
                mysqli_close($conexion);
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <span>Motivo pedido:</span>
            <textarea name="motivo" placeholder="Motivo" id="motivo"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div claspes="col">
            <span>Pedido:</span>
            <input type="text" name="pedido" id="pedido" placeholder="Pedido" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="button" name="enviar" class="boton" value="Guardar" id="guardar"  onclick="alta();">
</div>
```

La funcion que se utiliza en el onclick es la siguiente:

```
function alta(){        
    fecham=$('#fecha').val();
    fciam=$('#fcia').val();
    tipinsm=$('#tipins').val();
    motivom=$('#motivo').val();
    pedidom=$('#pedido').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'alta.php',
        data:{fecha:fecham,fcia:fciam,tipins:tipinsm,motivo:motivom,pedido:pedidom},
        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                alertify.success("agregado con exito");
            }else{
                alertify.success("Hubo un error al cargar");
            }
        }
    });}
```

Esto si funciona va al php donde se genera el insert en la base de datos, he aquí el código:

```
<?php
    require('conexion.php');
    $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
    $fcia=$_POST['fcia'];
    $motivo=$_POST['motivo'];
    $pedido=$_POST['pedido'];
    $idtipoInsumo=$_POST['tipins'];
    $borrado='1';
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,"insert into pedidosfarmacias 
                (idFarmacia,fecha,motivo,cantidad,idtipoInsumo,borrado)
                values ($fcia,'$fecha','$motivo',$pedido,$idtipoInsumo,$borrado)")
                or die("Problemas en el insert ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    echo $resultado; 
?>
```

Si el resultado es positivo deberia devolver 1 y eso iria a la funcion y mostrarme un cartel que diga "Agregado correctamente"
Lo que no entiendo es si le estoy errando en algo o porque no se ejecuta la llamada al ajax.
Si me pueden dar una mano les agradeceria.
Saludos

Comment: Deberias imprimir r para ver que devuelve alert(r); antes del if

Comment: @juanperez 
Imprime algo raro
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>1
Asi, no tengo idea jaja

Comment: esta devolviendo es  un html que proviene de alta.php fijate que tengas solo codigo php

Comment: revise de arriba a abajo y no tiene nada de html, habra algun error con la funcion?

Comment: Probablemente solo necesitas agregar `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` para asegurar que la salida será solo el resultado de la consulta.

Comment: @Triby osea en el php, como primera linea lo agrego, a eso te refieres no?

Comment: deberías cambiar la consulta sql por una más elaborada el echo al final del php debe estar encerrada por una condición y aparte mostrar echo '1';  para que el ajax pueda leerlo